# Difference between Pre-operation and Post Operation when do we go for pre operation,pre operation will work on retrieve?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is Pre operation will work on Retrieve, create, update then why post operation?
post operation will also work crud. then why pre operation. could you plz anybody clarify me

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx

Comment: Can you figure out why it makes a difference to do something before a CRUD operation takes place, or to wait until it is already done and committed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-operation:
  pipeline for plug-ins that are to execute before the main system operation.

```
Post-operation:
```

pipeline for plug-ins which are to execute after the main operation.:

```
For Example: Pre-Operation
```

Suppose we have a Business Requirement that Reports in CRM should not be deleted after they are sent.

So We will write a Plugin to be registered on `Pre-Operation` and check for the Send Date Time if it is a Sent Report we will throw an Exception with a message that unable to delete this report. `So our plugin executes before the main Operation` to prevent the delete.

```
For Example: Post-Operation
```

Suppose we have some entities like `Account`that we want to `Synchronize` with some External System. The we will write a Plug-in to be registered on `Post-Operation` and Send some notification/Data to the external System that we want to `Sync`

Comment: Yes.  A pre-operation on retrieve is usually used to filter your results in some manner.